# how to used control User of the masterpage

Tags: sharepoint-server, branding, sharepoint-on-prem

I need insert the control of User which is displayed by default in MasterPage of SharePoint 2013 in another part of my custom master page

[image: control login usuario SharePoint 2013]

Does anyone have any idea how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing this answer as per observation on my SPO site.

You can get the master page snippets using Design Manager

1. Click the gear icon on top right side of page.
2. Before site settings you will see an option "Design Manager". (This option available only if publishing feature enabled).
3. You have to click "Edit Master Pages" option from the left side links of page.
4. Click on your custom master page.
5. In the preview page top right of the page, you will find "SNIPPETS" option.
6. Here you will see "SIGN IN" option from the list of snippets. Click on that to generate code.
   [image]